# How do I execute code after a certain checkbox is selected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, datagridview

I have a datagridview with multiple checkboxes.  When the Finished checkbox is checked I need to execute linq code to update a specific table.  How do I find out if that specific check box is dirty and where do I write the code to pass the values I need to be passed to the table. Note that it is not the same table that the datagridview is based on.

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
 private void propertyInformationDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)propertyInformationDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3];

        DataGridViewRow row = propertyInformationDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewRow;

        System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
        newCityCollectionDataSet.PropertyInformationRow SelectedRow;

        SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)propertyInformationBindingSource.Current;
        SelectedRow = (newCityCollectionDataSet.PropertyInformationRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

        if (Convert.ToBoolean(checkCell.EditedFormattedValue) == true)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            var matchedCaseNumber = (from c in dc.GetTable<PropertyInformation>()
                                     where c.CaseNumberKey == SelectedRow.CaseNumberKey
                                     select c).SingleOrDefault();

            reportsSent newReport = new reportsSent();
            newReport.CaseNumberKey = SelectedRow.CaseNumberKey;
            dc.reportsSents.InsertOnSubmit(newReport);
            dc.SubmitChanges();

        }
    }
```

Do I need to endedit at some point is that the issue?

Comment: So there is a "Finished" checkbox on each row correct?

Comment: Let me know if you need any more help with the code as well, I'll be around all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from some of my code, all you need to do is create a "CellContentClick" event for your datagridview.

The easiest way to do this is select the Datagridview, go to properties and click on the lightning bolt. Scroll down to "CellContentClick" and double click in the empty box. This will auto generate the method you need to paste the following code into.

Make sure you rename my instances of "CustomersDataGridView" to whatever yours is named as well, intellisense should highlight invalid code in red that you need to replace.

Also, the "9" you see in the checkCell declaration needs to be changed to the index of your "Finished" check-box. If it is in the 3rd cell from the left, put a 2 there instead of a 9, as the indexing is 0 based.

**EDITTED to fix comments:**

```
private void CustomersDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.ColumnIndex.ToString() == "9")
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)CustomersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9];
        DataGridViewRow row = CustomersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewRow;

        if (Convert.ToBoolean(checkCell.EditedFormattedValue) && CustomersDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            //Do Work here.
            var z = row.Cells[0].Value; // Fill in the brackets with the column you want to fetch values from
            //z in this case would be the value of whatever was in the first cell in the row of the checkbox I clicked
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @KreepN.  I am guessing that I can use if(checkcell = -1) then the code I need etc.  As I did not define those as boolean but rather Int and I use -1 for true and 0 for false?

Comment: Honestly, due to the Convert.ToBoolean, I **think** you should be able to use my code without problem as it checks to see if the checkbox is checked (not the values associated with it) and passes into the if conditional if it is checked. If it doesn't work, just use the correct if(checkcell = -1) or if(checkcell.toString() == -1) method of your choice and you should be ok.

Comment: I will use your code then as its a bit cleaner. One last question just to make sure.  This will only execute when that check box CHANGES.  I just want to be sure as it drops a value into a table that sends a report to a client so its important that they only get a report once =).

Comment: It runs only when the actual box inside the cell is clicked. It won't even fire if you click around the box itself. The if conditional will only allow the code inside to fire when it goes from unchecked to checked.

Comment: okay I attempted this and it is also adding any clicked on rows regardless of if I am clicking the check box or not.  I will add the code as a reply so you can see it.

Comment: It's meant to run and execute code when something is clicked inside a cell that belongs to the DGV. We can just add a conditional to take care of it, give me a sec.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4427/discussion-between-kreepn-and-korrowan)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the CheckedChanged-Event

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do what you have to do...
}
```

Comment: You may want to include examples of how to connect the event to the method. I doubt he'd ask if he knew how to do that already.

Comment: @JsWOrk That is exactly what I need to understand =).

Comment: There are two ways to connect the event to the checkbox. 1) You can do it in Visual Studio in the designer by clicking on the checkbox, switching in properties window to the events tab, search for CheckedChanged entry and enter a name for the event handler. After pressing enter, Visual Studio will switch to code page showing the event method. 2) Got to the constructor of your window holding the checkbox. Insert follwing line after "InitializeComponents();": "checkBox.CheckedChanged += checkBox1_CheckedChanged;" Add after the constructor the code fragment mentioned above.